# ploting a function under condition with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am looking for a solution to this problem:

consider a function f (x) = 2x + 1, with x belonging to [0, 1000]. Draw the representative curve of f as a function of x, so that if ||f (x)|| <3 the representative curve of f is in red color and else represent the curve of f in blue color.

Help me because I am a new user of Matlab software

Comment: Could you paste the code you tried so far please?

Comment: For `x` between `0` and `1000`, and for the given linear function... the only red part you should see is in correspondance of `x < 1`.

Answer (score 2):

The code below should do the trick:

```
% Obtain an array with the desired values
y = myfunc(x);

% Get a list of indices to refer to values of y 
% meeting your criteria (there are alternative ways
% to do it
indInAbs = find((abs(y)<3));
indOutAbs = find((abs(y)>=3));

% Create two arrays with y-values
% within the desired range
yInAbs = y(indInAbs);
xInAbs = x(indInAbs);

% Create two arrays with y-values
% outside the desired range
yOutAbs = y(indOutAbs);
xOutAbs = x(indOutAbs);

% Plot the values
figure(1);
hold on;
plot( xInAbs, yInAbs, 'r')
plot( xOutAbs, yOutAbs, 'b')
legend('in abs', 'out abs', 'location', 'best')
```

There are alternative ways to do it which could be more efficient and elegant. However, this is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: A) do not answer questions without effort, as that's against the Stack Overflow model. B) Don't give code only answers, instead explain why the code does what the OP wants it to do, meaning that you should add text and/or comments in this post explaining why it works *especially* if you answer bad questions like this where the OP clearly states they don't understand a thing about the technology yet. As to the code itself: too much text. Just find one index and use + (or -)1 for the other index instead of using `find` two times and hand-duplicating a lot of lines.

Comment: @Adriaan thank you for your guidance, you are right. Regarding your comment on index+-1, I think that we search for a range of indexes. Can you clarify?

Comment: We don't search for a range, we search for a point. Anything up to that point is blue, anything beyond that point is red. No need to find that index twice. If you find your `indInAbs`, `indOutAbs` is per definition of `>=` `indInAbs+1`. Hence, using a `find` call twice is computationally heavy without having added benefit, and handcopying the same point (with 1 idx different) is obfuscated at best, and cumbersome when the point changes as you need to change lots of code instead of 1 variable to define the point of change.

Comment: So your blue range would be `1:indInAbs` and your red range `indInAbs+1:end`. Done and dusted with one variable, so that requires less code, less computation time and less hassle when you change the point of change.

Comment: @Adriaan I totally agree for this example. However, I have two questions: 1) What if the function is not monotonic and/or 2) if your x-array is not sorted? I can tell from the question that we are not specifically interested in this `f(x)` or the range of `x=0:1000`.

Comment: In that case: replace your `find` by simple logical indexing. Goes a lot faster too.

Answer (score 0):

Your threshold cannot be too low, otherwise it has not enough data to plot (if threshold=3) or cannot see the blue part. Here I use 500 such that you can see.

```
function plotSeparate
    clc
    close all
    k=0
    threshold=500
    for x=1:0.5:1000
        k=k+1
        y=f(x)
        if abs(y)<threshold
            t(k,:)=[x,y];
        else
            s(k,:)=[x,y];
        end
    end
    plot(s(:,1),s(:,2),'-r',t(:,1),t(:,2),'-b')
end

function y=f(x)
    y=2*x+1;
end
```